# How is the highest order term in the summation of kth powers generalized?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation

More specifically, I read that the highest order term for $\sum_{i=1}^n i^k$ is $\frac{1}{k+1}$$n^k$ because "Gauss’s trick is that $k + 1$-tuples with a single largest component have that component in one of $k + 1$ places" ([http://www.math.caltech.edu/~nets/cranks.pdf](http://www.math.caltech.edu/%7Enets/cranks.pdf)).  Is there an intuitive, combinatorial explanation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(n+1)^{k+1}-n^{k+1}=(k+1)n^k  +F (n,k)$

[F(n,k) has highest power 'k-1' of n]

$(n)^{k+1}-(n-1)^{k+1}=(k+1)(n-1)^k+F(n-1,k)$

........

........(writing till 1)

---

adding them all -> $(n)^{k+1} -1 = (k+1)(\sum_{r=1}^n r^k) +F(n,k) + F(n-1,k) ..............$

(obviously coefficient of highest power of n which is 'k+1' is 
$\frac{1}{k+1}$)

Comment: I understand what follows from line 1, but how do we establish that (+1)+1−+1=(+1)+(,)

Comment: oh that , it's called binomial theorm.I just opened $(n+1)^{k+1}$ by using it.

Comment: Sorry so it would be equal to $\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} ({{k+1}\choose{i}} (n)^{k+1-i}) - n^{k+1}$

Comment: yeah so first term of $(n+1)^{k+1}$ is $n^{k+1}$ which get cancelled.